# Getting error while running a Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

**Table structure**

```
Name     Null Type         
-------- ---- ------------ 
EMP_NO        NUMBER       
EMP_NAME      VARCHAR2(30) 
ADDRESS       VARCHAR2(15) 
PH_NO         NUMBER(10)   
DPT_NO        NUMBER
```

**Procedure**

```
create or replace procedure procedure1 (nom in employees.emp_no%type,
                                      vemp_name out employees.emp_name%type)
is                               
begin
    select emp_name into vemp_name from employees where emp_no=nom; 
end;
```

**Call**

```
exec procedure1(1);
```

It is showing error like

**Error**

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROCEDURE1'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I don't know why it is showing that error.  Please suggest me.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is easy enough to understand.  It's simple maths.  Your procedure has *two* parameters; your call only passes *one*.

To resolve this you need to pass a variable to receive the out parameter:

```
var n varchar2(30)   

exec procedure1(1, :n)

print n
```

Note the colon we need to use when referencing the SQL*Plus variable in SQL or PL/SQL.

---

> "after executing ur code am getting error Error report:"

Hmmm, either you are *not* executing my code or your code doesn't match what you have posted in your question.

Here is your table as presented...

```
SQL> create table employees ( 
  2    EMP_NO        NUMBER       
  3    ,EMP_NAME      VARCHAR2(30) 
  4    ,ADDRESS       VARCHAR2(15) 
  5    ,PH_NO         NUMBER(10)   
  6    ,DPT_NO        NUMBER )
  7    ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into employees values (1, 'MR KNOX', 'LONDON', 23, 10)
   2 /

1 row created.


SQL> insert into employees values (2, 'FOX IN SOX', 'BOSTON', 42, 20)
   2 /

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Here is your procedure  as presented ....

```
SQL> create or replace procedure procedure1 (nom in employees.emp_no%type,
   2                                      vemp_name out employees.emp_name%type)
   3 is                               
   4 begin
   5    select emp_name into vemp_name from employees where emp_no=nom; 
   6 end;  
   7  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Here is my demonstration of how to call it:

```
SQL> var n varchar2(30)   

SQL> exec procedure1(1, :n)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>  print n
N
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MR KNOX

SQL> exec procedure1(2, :n)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>  print n


N
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOX IN SOX

SQL>
```

Comment: i'm thinking if give a emp_name then it shows emp_name.is it possible.if it is possible then please give code

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  If my solution does not work the way you want please *edit* your question and clarify your actual requirements, perhaps by giving some sample data and desired output.

Comment: in stored procedure if give emp_no then while executing these procedure it will shows the emp_name  **Requirements**  `INPUT: emp_no(like 1,2,3...) Output:emp_name's(like Jim,Scott...)`

Comment: are you got it my requirements...?

Comment: That requirement is a rather different program.  You should ask it as a new question.

Comment: after executing ur code am getting error  Error report:
`ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROCEDURE1'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:`